# How to debug performance issues in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, performance, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

For the last couple of days, my web application has been very slow, sometimes returning a 503 error instead.

Locally the app runs fine.

With so many moving parts involved, how do I know where to look? Is it my code (and if yes how do I find what)? It is Amazon? Is it the database? Did I outgrow my instance?

I am using Amazon Elastic Beanstalk (1 small instance), with MySQL RDS (1 micro instance), and the code is in PHP. The site has relatively low traffic (about 1500 page views this past week).

Comment: The performance profile of micro instances uses a burst model. It will go up to 2 ECU's for a short period of time, then be capped at less than 1. Short of issues with your code/queries I would look at this. Check CPU usage in cloudwatch for RDS.

Comment: CPU usage appears as a percentage. It is on average at 20% and sometimes peaks at 30%. Does that mean I have room to grow until near 100%? Or is 30% too much?

Comment: If you are hitting the cap, it should be pushing 100% and getting stuck there. If you are not seeing that you should be OK from that perspective. Database queries are often the first thing I look at when trying to optimize however. Some people just don't get indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use xdebug to do profiling: http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler Then you can load that profile with a program that views cachegrind files (such as http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) to find the slow spots. You could also turn on the mysql slow query log and see if there are any trouble spots there. (In my.cnf: log-slow-queries = [path to the log file], then restart mysql)

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will look into those tools.